# Bootstrap 4.0.0 pen multi item carousel slider not working with bootstrap 4.5.3

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, carousel

I finally found a multi item carousel for bootstrap 4 that fits my requierements:

- Is responsive (it shows only 1 item in small screens)
- It has animations

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
    <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4 active">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400/000/fff?text=1" alt="slide 1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=3" alt="slide 3">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=4" alt="slide 4">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=5" alt="slide 5">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item col-md-4">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 7">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg text-muted"></i>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg text-muted"></i>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

See it working here:

https://codepen.io/WebDevWaw/pen/zPvaJy

The problem with that one is that it seems to work with bootstrap 4.0.0-beta but I am using 4.5.3 in my project. When changing the css link from 4.0.0-beta to 4.5.3 then only 1 item is shown as you can see in the following pen:

https://codepen.io/soyxan/pen/ZEaywvw

It should be easy to adapt but I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

in the link that doesn't work you are using different versions for css file and js file, may  it is the problem

```
bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

and

```
twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wanted to show that the issue was with the 4.5.3 css (not the JS). Anyway I modified the second pen to include de 4.5.3 css and js files and the problem is still there (you can check).

Comment: you can use custom css code in this page instead of yours https://azmind.com/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-items/